# Updating composed objects in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm working with Entity Framework 4.4 and I have the following issue working with disconected objects.
I have one class that has as a property an instance of another. Everything goes fine when I insert like this:

```
var thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
var adn = new Adn { Thumbnail = thumbnail };
var adnRepo = new AdnRepository();
adn = adnRepo.Create(adn);
```

In this case both adn and thumbnail are persisted to the DB. The persisting code goes something like this:

```
context.Set<T>().Add(instance);
```

The problem is when I try to update adn. It works ok for scalar properties but I don't know how to make it work for thumbnail.

```
var adn = new Adn();
var adnRepo = new AdnRepository();
adn = adnRepo.Create(adn);

var thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
adn.Thumbnail = thumbnail;
adn = adnRepo.Update(adn);
```

Update does something like this:

```
context.Entry(instance).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

In this case adn is saved but thumbnail isn't.

What are the alternatives that I have to make it work (note that my entities don't have id fields)

Comment: Are these POCO entities ?
If yes, did you use data annotations or fluent API to define the relations?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using a DbContext overriding OnModelCreating to define custom DB creation and I also have a DbMigrationsConfiguration Class with AutomaticMigrationEnabled = false